# Spring Annotations by name

Tags: java, spring, annotations, autowired

I have a question related with Spring annotations. In my (learning) project, I have defined two classes, and another class that have two properties, one of each of these types. 
In order to generate an error, I have defined two beans of the same class type in the XML, and I have used the @Autowired annotation in setter methods. Something like this:

```xml
<bean id="classA" class="beans.ClassA"></bean>
<bean id="otherclassA" class="beans.ClassA"></bean>
<bean id="classB" class="beans.ClassB"></bean>
```

```java
public class UpperClass{
   private ClassA classA;
   private ClassB classB;

   @Autowired 
   public void setClassA(ClassA classA){this.classA = classA}
   @Autowired 
   public void setClassB(ClassB classB){this.classB = classB}

   /* .
      .
      .
    */
}
```

In the main class, I get an instance of the applicationcontext for this bean, and print the content of the properties overriding the toString method, an easy test.
I have read that Spring Autowired annotation looks for the beans by type, so the test should fail, because there are two beans of ClassA class defined, but it works.
It also works using @Resource annotation without using any name in it.

I'm using Spring version 4.
I have changed the id of the beans to not match the class/setters names, and it fails, as expected.

Can anyone tell me why, or what I'm doing wrong?
Is Spring looking byName if it can not find the beans byType?

Comment: Try changing the id of the first bean in your xml and see what happens.

Comment: I´ve seen that if you change the class instead the bean id, you have to change not only the name of the setter parameter to get the error, you have to change also the setter method name to not match the bean id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring will look at method parameter names to resolve ambiguity when there are multiple beans matching the desired type. IMO it's excessively magical and another reason to avoid `@Autowired`. If you do end up using (or having to deal with others' use of) this behavior, IntelliJ's Spring plugin does a very good job of figuring out which bean will actually be injected at an autowiring site.

Comment: What is the suggested alternative to `@Autowired`?

Comment: @Andreas You could use @ Qualifier to resolve ambiguity

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve.
I had been looking for information about this issue, but I didn´t find the reason, it seems that this "magical behaviour" is not well known. I have tried with Resource annotation and works in the same way. I have had to change the beans id to get the error, and use @Qualifier and @Resource(name) to get it working, as expected.

Comment: Nothing a computer does is 'excessively magical'. This behaviour is both expected and documented. See "5.2 Autowiring by name" here: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire